# Can I use a rails partial to render options for a dropdown menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for all 50 States and then for some Classes I want people to be able to select. I put all the options in a partial and was hoping to be able to render the options inside the "options_for_select" area but it isn't working.

Any thoughts? Do I need to save the states and class values in a "reference only" table in my db?

Comment: You could add your complete `select` in the partial. Can you share your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper like so:

```
def states
    [
      ['Alabama', 'AL'],
      ['Alaska', 'AK'],
      ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
      // ETC...
    ]
end
```

and then the tag:

```
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(states) %>
```

and be sure the helper is called from your controller.

Comment: You can also use a hash instead of the array of arrays.